# What does "H" in "HStore" mean in PostgresDB data type name?

Tags: postgresql

I tried searching and after some search here I decided to reveal this secret with YOUR help.

Comment: I've read the documentation, and surely, I haven't noticed clear definition of that

Comment: Probably "hash" since key/value structures are called "hashes" in many languages.

Comment: You'd better ask that on the Postgres mailing list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely bet that `hstore` is a diminutive for hash-store, hash being a reference to the Perl datatype for key/value pairs.

Oleg Bartunov, co-designer of this datatype, mentions the relationship in the [-hackers mailing-list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.64.0801262241400.26876@sn.sai.msu.ru):

> have you seen contrib/hstore ? It's perl-like hash data type

Also in the original doc, before the adoption of hstore in the contrib section of PostgreSQL (this page dates back from 2003 or older):
http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/hstore/README.hstore
there are several references to Perl hashes to explain some operators:

> ```
> * hstore ? text - get value , perl analogy $h{key}
> * hstore || hstore - concatenation, perl analogy %a=( %b, %c );
> ```